# How to have photo interrupter drive a MOSFET when interrupted?

Tags: mosfet, photosensor

How do I get a photo interrupter drive a MOSFET when interrupted?

- I don't currently know what MOSFET I'm going to get.
- The battery is going to be two Energizer max 9V connected in series.
- The load is an electromagnet.

Comment: If you post your attempt at a schematic and ask specific questions we may be able to help.  But this isn't a design service, it's a Q&A site.  You also haven't specified your problem well enough for any kind of a useful answer.  Which interrupter? Which electromagnet? How much current?  What driving voltage?

Answer (score 2):

The photo interrupter will have a transistor output, either a PNP or an NPN type. Here's a circuit with an NPN style ([simulate it here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgbJy09xiUQKTnwHsA5oPyChk3kKoK2AJ1kjVYFLyqc4bCbhrTDBwcMUqTYfiEuaoyeGwBu4DeEJVWouwtpVi9grQCM6uAjxh4BiEgX4gAb4wIQDukWAeadFQbKle6m4oMpB6kYWGefKBOWl2eXiKuW71qs3FqRHNERpa1ba8Jq29kIadUoMAZjZ45dZ0otbYosHgKTbDatjTasUSc0a0i6aJ1XsRp0Unh+lUCLUZxQA2FBnXz1StULAQLITB2GDRbAeAgoIGGNprEY3OyDAAmFFqNEMt14nRAsIY4wAhgBXB4AF2qCAyzRRIEGqWJngyZNexQAHoJeGAkeTRDRyOUBMQAGoAHQAzgAhLH4-EMJQATzYQOZTU8bhoWmyjLQMUwMRMmACXJAACIAA4ACwA9viTYKAJYAO3FSiUOINdr1bEZSpihBiCFuIBItHAAgAwqKAMZGwWwy0mjGu31WAMewjMlA6gMgADKJoeDGtJstsNjm3oYAQ9BofpLMV1AAUTckJYKALIAeXTADEAKIAFVjtWsBD4SF1vMFIrFEullMRyLuDQOogyewBMWKQA)):

[image]

I've modeled the photointerrupter with an optocoupler. The circuit works as follows:

- not interrupted, NPN is on, pulls MOSFET gate low (off)
- interrupted, NPN is off, 10k resistor pulls MOSFET gate high (on).

Other notes:

- The solenoid (electromagnet) inductance used in the sim is a guess. Not super important
- The MOSFET should be sized according to what the solenoid needs, with an adequate gate-source breakdown voltage to sustain 18V
- The catch diode is essential: it prevents flyback voltage from damaging the FET

Comment: thank you so much, this will be really helpfull

Comment: Very good answer. Just a note: with 18V you can use a pull up resistor of 22K or even 47K to save battery power.

Comment: The LED is where most of the power is going anyway. A better power-saving strategy would be to pulse the LED periodically and sample the state of the sensor with a one-shot / missing pulse detect. This could be done with a dual CMOS 555 or a micro. Then the battery would last much, much longer.

Comment: the circuit wont be active for very long at a time .

Comment: 9V batteries don’t have a lot of capacity or current so they aren’t a good choice for driving a solenoid. They work best in low-drain applications.

Comment: i do have a spare power drill battery. its 15 volt but i dont know the current or amp hours.

Comment: Lots more than the 9V. Probably at least 1.5ah.